# How does Grakn compute rules when running a query for a transitive relation?

Tags: sql, inference, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm working in memSQL on a project to identify certain `batter` `pitcher` relationships in the MLB; where I look at what `batters` had the most success against various `pitchers` and `when`. With the goal of creating a heat map of `teams` and lineups of a specific year(s)(collection of `batters`) against various groups of `pitchers`.

I ran into a problem trying to query for teams with a positive net score against pitchers. When looking for all Batter of a given team.

I came across Grakn and this blog post: https://blog.grakn.ai/comparing-graql-to-sql-part-2-2-745f79e9528d

Seems that I could utilise rules to then query for something like this.

Taking a stab at the rule - I want to make `team performance` against a `pitcher` based on a collection of `batter performance` of that same `pitcher`.

I wrote this query, which would just query for `at-bat performance` where `batter` is in a `plays-for` with a given `team`. However the query doesn't give me the result I am expecting?

```
when {
(batting: $b, pitching: $p) isa at-bat;
(playing: $b, plays-for: $t) isa team;
}, then {
(plays-for: $c, pitching: $d) isa at-bat;
};
```

Also does anyone knows when these rules are computed and what is the performance overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Just to check quickly, are you defining the rule in your schema? Rules need to be inserted into Grakn using a `define` statement, since they are treated like schema elements. If you are trying to run it in-line in the query I would have thought you would get an error, but maybe that's not what you are doing and I am misunderstanding.

To answer the other question, rules are computed at query time, we detect which rules might change the outcome of a query and effectively make it a part of the query traversal, so in theory it works like a normal transitive search over a graph. In practice it's a bit different.